# How to put a third condition into a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I implement this query with the contition that the producer has at least 10 sold car?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `car`
INNER JOIN
    producer ON car.producer = producer.id
INNER JOIN
    owner ON car.owner = owner.id
WHERE
    owner.email IS NOT NULL
AND
    producer.email IS NOT NULL
AND
    owner.birth_date >= car.produce_year
```

the three table are:

```
TABLE car
id integer
owner integer
color varchar
type varchar 
producer integer
poduce_time integer

TABLE owner
id integer
first name varchar
last name varchar
address varchar
date_of_birth integer
place_of_birth varchar
email varchar

TABLE producer
id integer
name varchar
address varchar
email varchar
```

Comment: Nothing in your data model specifies "sold".  What does that mean?  Is that somehow equivalent to a car being owned by someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    car c
INNER JOIN
    producer ON c.producer = producer.id
INNER JOIN
    owner ON c.owner = owner.id
WHERE
    owner.email IS NOT NULL
AND
    producer.email IS NOT NULL
AND
    owner.birth_date >= c.produce_year
AND 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM car WHERE car.producer = c.producer) >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do this with a pre-filter on the `producers` using the mentioned condition on the first `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    car
INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT
              producer.*
          FROM
              producer
          INNER JOIN
              car ON car.producer = producer.id
          GROUP BY
              producer.id
          HAVING
              COUNT(*) >= 10 ) AS p ON p.id = car.producer
INNER JOIN
    owner ON car.owner = owner.id
WHERE
    owner.email IS NOT NULL
AND
    p.email IS NOT NULL
AND
    owner.birth_date >= car.produce_year
```

Also, the restrictions on the `where` clause can be transladed to the `joins` to reduced the query like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    car
INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT
              producer.*
          FROM
              producer
          INNER JOIN
              car ON car.producer = producer.id
          GROUP BY
              producer.id
          HAVING
              COUNT(*) >= 10 ) AS p ON p.id = car.producer AND p.email IS NOT NULL
INNER JOIN
    owner ON owner.id = car.owner
          AND owner.email IS NOT NULL
          AND owner.birth_date >= car.producer_year
```